# Tikz double plus notation incompatible with edge notation?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the example below I get the proper behavior when I use `--` (also `to`) to connect points along a path, but not when I use  `edge`. I'd like to use `edge` to get more control over the appearance of individual segments.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\path[draw] (0,0) -- ++(90:0.5) -- ++(30:0.5) --
++(330:0.5) -- ++(270:0.5) -- ++(210:0.5) -- cycle;\qquad

\tikz\path[draw] (0,0) edge ++(90:0.5) edge ++(30:0.5) edge
++(330:0.5) edge ++(270:0.5) edge ++(210:0.5) edge cycle;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The TikZ manual states : "an edge temporarily suspends the construction of the current path and a new path
is constructed." In your case, the main path is only `(0,0)`, and all edges are built from that point. If you want them to cycle, you can, each time, repeat the last reached point.

Comment: @marsupilam, please concert your comment to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe like this is one way ?

As Zarko points out, `edge`s are not meant as a replacement for the `to` operations (such as `--`) and, rather, are meant for drawing graphs between nodes.

#### Quoting the manual :

> If there are several edge operations in a row, **the start coordinate is the same for all of them** as their target coordinates are not, after all, part of the main path.
>
> However, there is one exception to this rule: If the edge operation is **directly preceded by a node operation**, then this just-declared node is the start coordinate [for the next `edge`]

Another way would thus be to insert a node at each step of the path to give fresh start to each `edge`. The drawback is that nodes take space by default.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
  % place the useful coordinates
  \path (0,0) coordinate (a--1) 
    foreach \x in {0,...,5} 
    { 
      -- ++(90-\x*60:.5) coordinate (a-\x)
    };
  % actually draw using edges, repeating last node each time
  \draw [blue,very thick]
    foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \lastX using \x-1] in {0,...,5}
    {
      (a-\lastX) edge [bend right=20] (a-\x)
    }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1! I think that `edge` is not intended to draw some (over many coordinates) path. Primarily is used to connect states in automaton and similar task. Maybe this should be emphasized (to be sure, I need to check manual first).